# Jquery: using two selectors for one .click event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have something like this:

```
$(".jq_elements").children("input").click(function()
```

How do I add another selector to it, so that same event gets fired up when either one is clicked.

Basically something like this would be needed:

```
$(".jq_elements, .jq_another_div").children("input").click(function()
```

Is something like this possible?

**edit:** I did try this the way that I described above. Turns out my code was a bit crooked, but its fine now.

Comment: These problems need not to appear here. Do a search: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+multiple+selectors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`$("selector, selector")`](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

That very syntax works. Do you want to call `.children("input")` on both?

Alternatively [`$.merge($("selector"), $("selector"));`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/)

Comment: shouldn't be 
$(".jq_elements input, .jq_another_div input").click(function()
the same as the version with .children("input")

Comment: @Benjamin yes but probably less efficient since your calling `children` twice.

Comment: ah Jared noticed what i meant: children is not necessary at all :)

Answer (score 5):

The way you showed should work.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

All you need is a comma delimiter.

EDIT: Why are you calling children()?

```
$(".jq_elements > input, jq_another_div > input").click(function(){
    // ?
});
```

The space is a selector, meaning all descendents that match the following select. So `.jq_another_div input` will find all child inputs within the element with jq_another_div as a classname.

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: To replicate what `children("input")` is accomplishing, the selector really should be `".jq_elements > input, jq_another_div > input"`