# Can multiple IDs be included in a jQuery "on click"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two on click event handlers that are nearly identical:

```
$('#imgPreTravel').on( "click", function() {
    $('#preTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTSec0').removeClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
});

$('#imgPostTravel').on( "click", function() {
     $('#preTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
     $('#postTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
     $('#postTSec0').removeClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
});
```

(the only difference being the IDs - `imgPreTravel` and `imgPostTravel`).

Can I combine them into one on click function and, if so do they need to be comma-separated? IOW, should it be like this, similar to the way multiple classes can be assigned to an element:

```
$('#imgPreTravel #imgPreTravel').on( "click", function() {
    $('#preTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTSec0').removeClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
});
```

...or like this, as if the IDs are arguments in a method call:

```
$('#imgPreTravel, #imgPreTravel').on( "click", function() {
    $('#preTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTSec0').removeClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
});
```

?

Comment: The last one works exactly like you want, doesn't it? Didn't you try?

Comment: "Does not show any research effort" would definitely fit here.

Comment: `jQuery(selector)` returns a set of matched elements; thus the question is 'How to match two elements by ID?'. All jQuery methods work on this collection, either applying to everything (as in the case of `click`) or applying to the first element in the jQuery collection (as in the case of `val`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most definitely do this, with comma separated selectors.

```
$('#imgPreTravel, #imgPreTravel').on('click', function() {
[...]
```

...would be almost the correct approach, though, in your example, `#imgPreTravel` is the same `id` twice and, would do no good in this case. You'll actually only wire to the first DOM element with that `id`. See the [jQuery Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) docs for more information...

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rsq3fhLj/) - with `#imgPreTravel` and `#imgPostTravel` example selectors

```
<div id="imgPreTravel">pre</div>
<div id="imgPostTravel">post</div>
```

---

```
$('#imgPreTravel, #imgPostTravel').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Already Answered:

answered Feb 2 '11 at 21:11

Rains
97.4k27250312
[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879888/jquery-using-two-selectors-for-one-click-event)

> **"**    `$("selector, selector")`
>
> That very syntax works. Do you want to call `.children("input")` on both?
>
> Alternatively `$.merge($("selector"), $("selector"));` **"**

*I would have commented but I don't have a high enough reputation*

Comment: This would be a "close", but I don't think you have rep for that too.

Comment: you need 3000 rep to [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: oh okay, i see now.  I'm trying to answer more questions

Comment: @scniro You only need 15 rep to flag a question for closure (puts it in the review queue where 3k users can cast votes).

Comment: got it thanks @MaximillianLaumeister. Flagging is different than casting a close vote but I see what you're saying

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason you think it would be clearer you could do this:

```
function clickfun() {
    $('#preTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTravel').addClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
    $('#postTSec0').removeClass('finaff-form-help-hide');
});

$('#imgPreTravel').on( "click", clickfun);
$('#imgPostTravel').on( "click", clickfun);
```

or

```
$('#imgPreTravel, #imgPostTravel').on( "click", clickfun);
```